# flutter format currency in texformfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I have a flutter app which accepts an amount of money as input using a textformfield. I would like to format the input in textformfield so that whatever is being input can be formatted as currency copmlete wiht thousand separator commas. I have tried using the intl package number formatter but all I can do is print it to the command line.

Here is how it looks currently

[image: current look]

This is how I would like it to look like

[image: desired look]

This is the textfield code

```
  TextEditingController currencyControler = TextEditingController();

  String? amount;

 TextFormField(
              controller: currencyControler,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter an amount';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (String? value) {
                amount = value;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.money_outlined),
                labelText: "Amount",
                hintText: 'Enter an amount',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

How can I format the input so that the comma separators appear as any number is being entered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.Used `intl` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) for number formation

Your functions:

```
  TextEditingController currencyControler = TextEditingController(); 
  String formNum(String s) {
    return NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(
      int.parse(s),
    );
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
   TextFormField(
              controller: currencyControler,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.money,
                  )),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (string) {
                string = '${formNum(
                  string.replaceAll(',', ''),
                )}';
                currencyControler.value = TextEditingValue(
                  text: string,
                  selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
                    offset: string.length,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: Hey, how to get the value as a plain integer/double? For example the text is 200000. When i enter in the form, it will become 200,000 right? But i got 200,000 when i call `controllerName.text`, which is not right.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal which you have entered and what do you want? If you entered `200000` in textfield it returns `200,000`. the `,` after 3 digits

Comment: Yes, i entered 200000 in textfield it returns 200,000. the , after 3 digits.
But i want to get the plain integer.. I mean the 200000. Not with the `,` in every after 3 digits.. This value will cause error if you send it to backend

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal If you want `2000000` in textfield just remove `onChanged` method

Comment: But if i remove `onChanged` method, then the function wont work to add `,` after 3 digits right?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal it already add to `,` after 3 digits have you try my answer?

Comment: Yeah, remove the whole block and also the content of onChanged (string){}` right? I already did this and i get the `200000`. But the function to add `,` after 3 digits didnt work